# Какой способ указания размера шрифтов наилучший?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

px, pt, %, em? Какой-нибудь еще? Я по привычке использую pt и px, хочется найти идеальный вариант на текущий момент. Мне кажется, что px лучше тем, что современные браузеры уже научились нормально масштабировать шрифты, а также тем, что, по сравнению с %, у px меньше подводных камней (вложенные элементы, т.д.). Если накидаете ссылок со сравнениями различных вариантов и типичными ситуациями, где что применять - буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут достаточно понятно разложили по полочкам - [CSS Font-Size: em vs. px vs. pt vs. percent](http://habrahabr.ru/post/42151/). Забегая вперед, скажу, что **проценты** и **em** имеют ряд приемуществ и все же **%** выигрывает. А дальше читайте и делайте выводы сами.

Comment: На мой взгляд, статья уже не актуальна. Пиксельные размеры отлично масштабируются всеми браузерами, как я заметил. Но за ссылку спасибо, хороша описана разница между типами.

Comment: Может быть, может быть. Но тогда надо еще вспомнить про мобильные устройства. Для них размер шрифтов желательно задавать в относительных единицах или, что еще лучше указывать аргументы свойства font-size в значениях small, medium, или large.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, надо всегда исходить из условий конкретной задачи. Где-то выгодно использовать px, где-то % или em. Я согласен больше с [[@Deonis](/users/4058/deonis)](/users/4058/deonis), но у **em** тоже есть "козырь в кармане". В процентах и пикселях вам не удастся задать число с тремя знаками после запятой.

**Дополнение по теме комментария**

Я, если честно, таких статей не встречал. Возможно, потому что нет в них смысла. В своё время было популярно спорить какой макет использовать - фиксированный или плавающий. И вот Ваш вопрос напоминает отклик тех времён. Я встречал только статьи, что для большего контроля над шрифтами лучше использовать `em`, как 62.5% от шрифта по умолчанию. Читал, что в других единицах, кроме `px`, вообще нет смысла, потому что все они в конечном итоге пересчитываются в px....Вот и получается, что решает каждый сам, исходя из своей задачи.

Comment: В идеале - хотелось бы найти статью, подробно описывающую, в каких случая что лучше использовать.

Comment: Хотя конечно же сказать, что их абсолютно нет, я не могу. если что - делитесь))