# В каких единицах верстать?

Tags: html5, css3

Подскажите какие единицы использовать при верстке.

1. Для шрифта?
2. для ширины блока в `em` или `%`?
3. Padding, margin, border в каких единицах указывать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Для шрифтов смотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/111789/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9/111794#111794)
- Для блоков `em`, `px` или `%` зависит от конкретного случая
- Для отступов и рамки `px` и `em`